# Requests to python API stalled by chrome for 10 seconds for no reason. [BaseHTTPServer + Chrome]

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, basehttpserver

*Overview of the problem*

I am running a webpage and an API written in python. The webpage sends some data to the python API in a POST request, which processes it and sends it back. The API works fine with curl requests and console AJAX requests. However, when I load the webpage in a new tab, all POST requests for the first 10 seconds or so are ‘stalled’ (not carried out by Chrome) until they fail. After around 10 seconds POST requests work fine, and the python API catches a broken pipe (ERRNO 32, logs below). If I hard refresh the tab, then the site immediately works and the request isn’t stalled at all, however if I open a new tab with the site in then again there’s this 10 second delay.

*Specifics*

This only happens on Chrome, it works fine on Firefox and Safari. I have run the API and the webpage on both localhost and an AWS instance, and there is still the ~10 second delay, after which it works fine. It happens on chrome on other computers and works on Firefox on other computers.

*How I've tried to fix it*

Chrome apparently stalls requests when its either negotiating a proxy connection or reaches its limit of 6 TCP connections. I don’t know why doing a hard-reset wouldn’t cause it to have to re-negotiate its connection to the API, or why it wouldn’t have to do that each time. Even if it is doing that, its shouldn’t consistently take around ~10 seconds should it? I’ve also ensured that the site is not reaching 6 TCP connections.

*Potential problem?*

I have no problems with the HTTP request stalling if I change the request to be from another site, and this issue is specific to Chrome, so I’m wondering if Chrome implements XMLHTTPRequests in a way that BaseHTTPRequests doesn’t know how to deal with, and that’s leading to the broken pipe. But I don’t know why it always fixes itself after ~10 seconds each time.

I’ve spent many hours on this now, any help would be massively appreciated please!

HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>OSR Web</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "http://localhost:1234";

      http.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
              var bestGuess = http.responseText;
              console.log(bestGuess);
          }
      }

      document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send("TestData");
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Python API:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def _set_headers(self):
      self.send_response(200)
      self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
      self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      self.end_headers()
   def do_GET(self):
      self._set_headers()
      self.wfile.write("OSR API Active")
   def do_POST(self):
      print "received"
      self._set_headers()
      self.data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
      inputData = self.data_string
      print inputData 
      self.wfile.write("Received\n")

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=1234):
   server_address = ('', port)
   httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
   print 'Starting HTTPD'
   httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

Broken pipe error message:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2017 15:34:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

----------------------------------------

Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56506)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock

    self.process_request(request, client_address)

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request

    self.finish_request(request, client_address)

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request

    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 657, in __init__

    self.finish()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 716, in finish

    self.wfile.close()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 283, in close

    self.flush()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush

    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

----------------------------------------

received

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2017 15:36:45] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

TestData
```

[Screenshot of the chrome network tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFyHJ.png)

Comment: What task does `httpd.serve_forever()` perform? Have you filed a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)?

Comment: @guest271314 'httpd.serve_forever()' starts the server. I haven't filed a bug, I wanted to see if anyone here could see if it was something wrong with my code first.

Comment: Are you intentionally sending the `POST` request twice? You have `http.open("POST", url, true);` on page load and button click. Does it work if you remove the request that fires immediately?

Comment: If you didn't see this question, it could be the culprit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650238/processing-simultaneous-asynchronous-requests-with-python-basehttpserver

Comment: `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` is a primitive socket server that cannot handle concurrent requests. This causes all kinds of stalls and errors. You should not use it in production. If you have to use `BaseHTTPServer`, at least add a [`ThreadingMixIn`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn).

Comment: @RobM. I wasn't intentionally doing that, and kicked myself when I saw your comment! However, having removed the immediate POST request it still doesn't work in chrome. I did find that it worked fine in incognito mode, so I cleared my cache and disabled all my extensions but it still didn't work in normal browsing. (I'll edit my original post to remove the double POST request). I'll check your second comment now.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Its just for a proof of concept. If the problem continues I' will change over to another library though. I'll check 'ThreadingMixIn' out now. Thank you :)